# Remove spacing between every TextView in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, border

I've been facing spacing issues in items (`Textview`) of `ListView`. Please don't tell me this is a possible duplicate because this is not. Here spacing is occurred due to border drawable I used. I've been using this `ListView`

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="184dp"
    android:id="@+id/googleMapLocations"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    />
```

and created layout for its row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/googleMapUserLocationSingleRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:singleLine="true"
android:background="@drawable/redborder" />
```

Code for border is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="#FF0000"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Using above scenario I got spaces in between list items and I don't know why. How can I remove spaces between list items. Please find screenshot attached.

[image]
I don't know how to remove space between list items.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like there's margin at the top of the textviews. Try setting

```
    android:layout_margin="0px"
```

If this doesn't work, as a workaround you could make a red line and use that as a separator. I know that's not a solution, but it would give you the result you want.